# why is my 9png photo is not centered?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, resources

I have an image which I see centered in the graphic editor (not xml).

However, when I run the application I see my `9.png` image is squeezed a bit to the left.

How can I fix this?

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="25dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/leftMargin"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/search_engine_button"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

..

..

..
```

Comment: because your linearlayout is horizontal

Comment: @njzk2 how to fix? change to what?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `LinearLayout` is set to `wrap_content`:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

This means that it will take as much space as to wrap the content inside it.
If you want make some room in the layout to center a component horizontally, put `layout_width="fill_parent"`.

Also, the `layout_weight="1"` seems redundant here, as the `ImageButton` has a fixed width and wrap_content for height.

Comment: I have tried. it didn't help. It's if the image doesn't start at it's original left top corner, but on the line of (15,0)